# Linux Mint 18: Network manager not showing wifi access points

Tags: linux, wifi

**Laptop:** Lenovo T410

**OS:** Linux mint 18

**Kernel:** 4.4.0-47-generic

**Network card (output from lspci):**

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

**Network manager:** `network-manage 1.2.2-0ubunt`

If I do a fresh start with my Laptop, the wifi accesspoints do not get shown at network-manager applet. But the known network connections get connected and work.

After `sudo service network-manager restart` it works like a charm and the available access points are visible in network-manager applet.

Strangely enough, after fixing it with the restart of network-manager and then suspend and wake up it still works. Seems to be just the first boot up where it is a problem.

Used to work like a charm in Linux Mint 17!

How to debug?

Comment: After boot `systemctl status NetworkManager`  You get a  Main PID: 804 in my case 804. `journalctl _PID=804`

Comment: It is possible that nm-applet is starting before something else that it needs is started. To test, try putting a delay in the nm-applet startup file, located at `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`. Change the line `Exec=nm-applet` to `Exec=sh -c "sleep 30; nm-applet" &`.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the power saving for your wireless card:

```
iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

Disable `802.11n` and enable software encryption:

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Add the following lines:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
options iwlwifi swcrypto=1
```

Unload the `wl` module:

```
rmmod wl
```

Comment: Seems to work! A short explanation would be nice, also for others :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the nm bugzilla they mention [this](https://github.com/NetworkManager/network-manager-applet/commit/c7533cfcd9c761a152a66f608808187df3155521) important commit. Update applet at least to 1.4.4.